# Weird behavior of cylinder shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I am trying to draw a cylinder to represent a database in a diagram of mine. I have written this code, inside a much bigger document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
            \node (db1) [cylinder,
                         draw=black,
                         fill=blue!30,
                         aspect=0.8,
                         minimum width=2cm,
                         minimum height=1.5cm,
                         shape border rotate=90] {SOME TEXT};
            \node (db2) [cylinder,
                         draw=black,
                         fill=blue!30,
                         aspect=0.8,
                         minimum width=2cm,
                         minimum height=1.5cm,
                         shape border rotate=90,
                         right of=db1] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the addition of text seems to break the aspect ratio. The output I get is this

[image: weird behavior of cylinder shapes]

Did I do something wrong or is this the expected behavior? I needed the cylinder like the second image, but having some text inside.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the fact that the node shape was designed to be horizontal, so the text width is used for determining the length of the cylinder (not the width). If you don't need the shape to adapt its width automatically, you can leave the node text empty and instead use `label=center:SOME TEXT` in the `node` options to place the text.

Comment: @Jake it sounds like a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a lower value for `aspect`. Here it is with value of `0.25`. The closer it's to 1, the more like yours. If you tried `0.10` it would almost be a rectangular shape.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]

    \node (db1) [cylinder, 
        fill=blue!30,
        shape border rotate=90, 
        draw,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        minimum width=2cm,
        shape aspect=.25,] {Some text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how does `aspect` and `shape aspect` differ from one another?

Comment: @Mauren They don't. I just tested it with another shape and writing only `aspect`.

Comment: @Mauren However I've always seen `shape aspect` being used. And if you check the [Tikz Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 221, the actual key is `shape aspect`.

Comment: I probably got a bad example while looking around.

Comment: With minimum width the shape aspect depend from text in shape (try omit the text in node). The aspect is preserve if you define 'text width' instead of minimum width.

Comment: @Mauren did the answer fix your problem? If yes, consider accepting it so the question is not marked as unanswered.

Comment: @Mauren No problem! I was just reminding you in case you had forgotten. If you were not satisfied yet, then it would have been different. Glad it helped!