# Drawing proportional cylinders with broken down parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have constructed a cylinder breakdown inspired by
[Draw two cylinders and use clipping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338115/draw-two-cylinders-and-use-clipping)

Unfortunately, I find the behavior of the cylinder shape quite confusing.
In "principle", they should all sum to 10cm height but none of them actually have same height.
The first two even differ in appearance because of the label.
This is discussed here
[Weird behavior of cylinder shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241992/weird-behavior-of-cylinder-shape-in-tikz)
but I hardly find the answer satisfactory since it does not really explain why the text would impact the lid portion of the drawing or how to repair that behavior.

Replacing \theasp by a very small value 0.000001 makes rectangle of equal heights.
Why is this property destroyed by the cylinder shape?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylw}{1.15}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\stepx}{1.5}   
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\theasp}{.78}
        \tikzset{mycyl/.style={cylinder,shape border rotate=90,minimum width=\cylw cm,cylinder uses custom fill, shape aspect=\theasp}}
        
        \node (db) [mycyl,
        minimum height=10 cm,draw,
        cylinder body fill = magenta!10, cylinder end fill = magenta!40,
        anchor = south] at (0,0) {1};
        \node (db-text) [mycyl,
        minimum height=10 cm,draw, 
        cylinder body fill = magenta!10, cylinder end fill = magenta!40,
        anchor = south] at (\stepx,0) {text};
        
        \node (db-slice1) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=3 cm,
        cylinder body fill = green!10, cylinder end fill = green!40,
        anchor = south] at (2*\stepx,0) {.3};
        \node (db-slice2) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=7 cm,
        cylinder body fill = red!10, cylinder end fill = red!40,
        above=0pt of db-slice1.before top, anchor= after bottom] {.7};
                
        \node (db-slice3) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=3 cm,
        cylinder body fill = green!10, cylinder end fill = green!40,
        anchor = south] at (3*\stepx,0) {.3};
        \node (db-slice4) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=3 cm,
        cylinder body fill = green!10, cylinder end fill = green!40,
        above=0pt of db-slice3.before top, anchor=after bottom] {.3};
        \node (db-slice5) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=3 cm,
        cylinder body fill = green!10, cylinder end fill = green!40,
        above=0pt of db-slice4.before top, anchor=after bottom] {.3};
        \node (db-slice6) [mycyl, draw,
        minimum height=1 cm,
        cylinder body fill = red!10, cylinder end fill = red!40,
        above=0pt of db-slice5.before top, anchor=after bottom] {.1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would draw the cylinders with directly with tikz, creating a macro for such purpose. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mypink} {HTML}{F899D1}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{E6FFE6}
\definecolor{salmon} {HTML}{FF9999}

\newcommand{\cylinder}[5] % position (lower base center), radius, height, color, text
{%
  \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
    \draw[fill=#4!50!white] (-#2,#3) -- (-#2,0) arc (180:360:#2 cm and 0.5*#2 cm) -- (#2,#3);
    \draw[fill=#4] (0,#3) ellipse (#2 cm and 0.5*#2 cm);
    \node at (0,0.5*#3-0.5*#2) {#5};
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cylinder{(0  ,0)}{0.5}{10}{mypink} {1}
  \cylinder{(1.5,0)}{0.5}{10}{mypink} {text}
  \cylinder{(3  ,0)}{0.5} {3}{mygreen}{.3}
  \cylinder{(3  ,3)}{0.5} {7}{salmon} {.7}
  \cylinder{(4.5,0)}{0.5} {3}{mygreen}{.3}
  \cylinder{(4.5,3)}{0.5} {3}{mygreen}{.3}
  \cylinder{(4.5,6)}{0.5} {3}{mygreen}{.3}
  \cylinder{(4.5,9)}{0.5} {1}{salmon} {.1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This is a very elegant solution.  Marked a solved for myself although I will simply mention that it does not clarify why the premade 'cylinder' shape is behaving so badly.